losing product ownership
I've been appointed as product owner of an application.  I have a good understanding of we need and how to achieve it.  So I jump wherever I see I can contribute to achieve the goal.
Usually that is some technical stuff even if I'm not the technical leader (the project is related with big data analysis)
The business analyst is helping me when I ask, in defining some concepts and whit some investigation.
However the business analyst started to contact stakeholders to define the roadmap of the product,  mapping features and capabilities.... which I realize is actually the PO job.
I feel I'm losing my ownership,  my leadership, as well as the project.
On the other side,  my contribution is still perceived as important,  but rolewise, nobody understand who I am and what I am doing.
I end up being a "crucial contributor"
Not the first time that is happening to me

The Product Owner is not the “leader.” It is a defined role in Scrum and other frameworks. This seems more like an organizational culture problem focused on delegated authority (or the lack of it), or possibly even a stylistic issue. It might be more suitable for The Workplace since as written your org structure and roles aren't really aligned with the  job functions as defined by most agile frameworks.


I've been appointed as product owner of an application.

Within the organization, someone has positional power over you and the business analyst. It may be worth getting this person - your manager and the business analyst's manager, if they aren't the same person - involved in a conversation about roles and responsibilities. This would include both a clear understanding of your role, responsibilities, accountabilities, and authority on the product or project, but also that of the business analyst.

I have a good understanding of we need and how to achieve it. So I
jump wherever I see I can contribute to achieve the goal.
Usually that is some technical stuff even if I'm not the technical
leader (the project is related with big data analysis)

When you're in a leadership position, sometimes jumping in is the wrong thing to do. Sometimes, it's not only not jumping in, but also saying no and making sure that the people with specific roles and responsibilities around move the team closer to achieving the goal.
Although it's good that you are there and have the necessary skills and knowledge, leaders should empower the people around them. If people are genuinely stuck, find ways to convey your expertise and avoid doing the work - facilitate, teach, and partner up rather than doing work beyond product management as much as possible. It may also be good to wait to be asked rather than jumping in.
I'd also question how time is spent. If you're jumping in to help with these things outside the core duties of a product owner, how are you also finding time to get product owner work done?

The business analyst is helping me when I ask, in defining some
concepts and whit some investigation.
However the business analyst started to contact stakeholders to define
the roadmap of the product, mapping features and capabilities....
which I realize is actually the PO job.

Work typically done by a product owner can be delegated. Although a product owner may be accountable for communicating with stakeholders and putting together roadmaps and backlogs, the product owner could delegate these things to someone else while remaining accountable. If the business analyst has skills and expertise in these things and sees you jumping in to contribute where you have skills and expertise, they could see this as an invitation to jump in and contribute to these.

I feel I'm losing my ownership, my leadership, as well as the project.
On the other side, my contribution is still perceived as important,
but rolewise, nobody understand who I am and what I am doing.

Based on everything else, it seems like you're either not asserting leadership or demonstrating behaviors that don't match what you want to see the rest of the team do. This is leading to the confusion.

I end up being a "crucial contributor"

There's nothing wrong with this. There's nothing wrong with a first-among-equals approach. In fact, I'd go so far as to suggest that this is a key component of self-organizing, self-managing teams. Anyone on the team can demonstrate leadership principles, especially by exerting expert power because of their expertise, skills, and training rather than power derived from their position in the organization.

Well, I feel that I have delegated everything, from designing the roadmap, to communication with stakeholder, but without my daily work, there would be no product delivery. Which role is that?

@Glasnhost What is the daily work that you do?

this is a financial application. I try to understand complex requirements and explain them to developers, I write acceptance criteria, I decide some priorities both high level and low level,  I troubleshoot results and analyse bugs, I analyse data, I create benchmarking datasets I unblock situations with developers, I ask clarifications to business expert,  I give inputs and comments to some kind of roadmap definition, I discuss with scrum master how to improve, I discuss priorities with tech leader, I try to define quarter goals, and report to at least 2 managers, I transfer knowledge

@Glasnhost Some of these things are clearly product management functions - understanding and explaining requirements, prioritization, goal planning. But you should find ways to stop doing the rest so you can do the product management functions currently being done by the business analyst. In my experience, the business analyst should be the one working on analyzing bugs and helping to troubleshoot or helping with dataset creation and doing low-level planning. This would let you take on more of the stakeholder management and become more involved in roadmapping.

I've lost it. Basically I thought that my job was to understand the requirements from the users and transform them in a product. The new business analyst, questioned all the requirements from the users and proposed a new product vision based on his own ideas. Which I couldn't do because either I didn't think that was my job, either because it's the first time I'm working on this kind of product. So I asked the BA to investigate...

It would be worth organising a session with the whole team to define roles and responsibilities.
Perhaps you could start the session by talking about your passion for doing the product owner role?
Make sure you document the outcome of the meeting and ensure that everyone in the team agrees with that outcome.

We did that. We defined work streams. We assigned responsibles to each one. But in the end each individual starts to deal with what she/he is more comfortable with. I don't understand if I can still be the product owner, even if somebody else is actually drawing the roadmap

Perhaps it would be worth scheduling regular check-ins where the team reviews the work streams and assigned responsibilities? I guess my advice would be to not let the situation fester. I suspect that won't be good for your hapiness or mental health.

Not really stressed about that, I'm more thinking about my career strategy. I'm delivering something but it is not very visible what I'm doing

Losing authority/ownership of an effort is frustrating - I'm sorry that happened. At the outset of the next product/project (or now) you can:

Gather stakeholders to align on team norms (ways of working, roles, responsibilities, etc).
Establish the PO's scope: the product's health, roadmap, backlog prioritization, assist in story refinement, etc.
Check in on your role's scope with team retrospectives & client conversations.

Partner with your Scrum Master to facilitate these conversations & reinforce working agreements. Your future outcomes should be better.
